# ajax responsetext has extra data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use ajax to check if there is a certain record in the database, using the variables **'zer'** and **'modify'** to search for the record containing those values  (see the code below).

If the record is found in the database, I return "found" from the php ajax code to the javascript; otherwise I return "not found"

**I also store the value of 'zer' and 'modify' into the SESSION before I return the "found" or "not found"**  from the php ajax code.

The response text looks like this when the record is found in the database:

```
        array(2) {
            ["zer"]=>
              string(2) "someVal"
            ["modify"]=>
              string(1) "anotherVal"
                 }
        found
```

I only want the "found" returned here and for some reason the responseText is returning the Session variables that I set up before the return.

Why is this, and how can I precisely control *exactly* what is returned from the Ajax call?
I tried using some buffer flushing php calls (see the code) to no effect.  I've read a lot of Ajax posts but I cannot find one that explains how to have **precise, exact control** over what gets returned from my ajax, or whether storing my 'zer' and 'modify' values into the SESSION before I return the responseText is some kind of "no-no."

Here is the code (NOTE: the database lookup code works 100% and correctly finds the record if it is present -- the code below has been tested for both the 'found' and 'not found' situations and correctly locates the record if it is present).

EDIT:  I use some output buffering PHP calls in an attempt to control any output buffering that may be happening, but this did not help.  See these buffer calls below.

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var zer = "someVal";
 var modify = "anotherVal";

 if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 var theResponseText; 

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        theResponseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("responseText is >>>" + theResponseText + "<<< that.");

        if( theResponseText == 'notfound')
        {
            return;
        }
        else if( theResponseText == 'found')
        {
            alert("We found the record!.")
        }
    }
 }

 ajaxText = "handler.php?zer=" + zer + "&modify=" + modify;
 xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxText, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP CODE in handler.php

```
 $zer = $_GET['zer'];
 $modify = $_GET['modify'];

 $theDB = connectToDb();  

 $query = "SELECT * FROM " . Dbases::$MyDB_TABLE 
        . " WHERE BINARY " . dbConstants::$ZERS 
        . " IN ('" . $zer . "')"
        . " AND BINARY " . dbConstants::$MODIFYS
        . " IN ('" . $modify . "')";

 $result = mysql_query($query);


 if($result)
 {
       $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
       if($numrows > 0)
       {
           $bFound = true;
       }
 }
 closeDB($theDB);

// now erase the php output buffering, start a new output buffer,
// echo the result, then flush the php output buffer so that the
// Ajax response text has *exactly* what I 'echo' here and nothing else.
// NOTE: this did *not* help.

if(! $bFound)
{
   ob_flush();
   while (@ob_end_flush()); 
   //ob_end_flush();
   //ob_end_clean();
   //ob_end_flush();       
   ob_start();

   //echo "notfound";
   print "notfound";

   ob_end_flush();
   //ob_end_clean();

   // clear out the session vars
   $_SESSION['zer'] = "";
   $_SESSION['modify'] = "";
   return;
}   
else 
{
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();  

    //echo "found";
    print "found";

    ob_end_flush();
    //ob_end_clean();

    $_SESSION['zer'] = $zer;
    $_SESSION['modify'] = $modify;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using output buffering?

Comment: @php_nub_qq  I use some output buffering PHP calls in an attempt to control any output buffering that may be happening, but this did not help.

Comment: I think these attempts are what is causing you trouble, try removing the buffering and see if it works.

Comment: @php_nub_qq  You see, the buffering calls were put there to fix the issue but had no effect.  In other words -- the code above never had php buffer calls originally.  I only added the buffer calls after I discovered that the responseText **erroneously** contained my 2 SESSION values.  Only reason I left them in the code above was to illustrate things I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  One of the team members, at some point, stuck a var_dump way up in the source file and I didn't catch it until just now.   I commented out the var_dump() and voila, the responseText is as expected, and I eliminated all the php buffer function calls as well.